# Creating a grouped bar plot of means using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
 dput(pct.df)
structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), gender = c("male", 
"female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), var_a_pct = c(33.3333333333333, 
16.6666666666667, 50, 50, 50, 33.3333333333333), var_b_pct = c(50, 
75, 50, 75, 75, 75), var_c_pct = c(50, 75, 75, 100, 75, 75), 
    var_d_pct = c(50, 25, 0, 25, 50, 50), var_e_pct = c(25, 0, 
    50, 0, 50, 25), var_f_pct = c(25, 25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_g_pct = c(25, 
    25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_h_pct = c(25, 25, 0, 50, 50, 25), 
    avg = c(35.4166666666667, 33.3333333333333, 28.125, 50, 56.25, 
    41.6666666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

How should I go about in creating a graph like this.

[Red & Blue represents group A & B - it shows all the variables (e.g. var_a, var_b and etc...) in a single graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BSmM.png)

In my desired graph, I am trying to plot the mean of each var (including the avg to look at group average) for group A and B. The y-axis is the averaged percentage.

I am new to R and stackoverflow. Do let me know if there is anything I should have included in my questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the mean of each variable (including the average) by `group`, you can do:

```
pct.df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "Variable") %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = group, x = Variable, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
    ylab("Mean") +
    theme_classic()
```

Output:

[image: Grouped Barplot of Mean Value]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I feel silly leaving out such a crucial detail. I am trying to get the mean of each var (including the avg to look at group average) for group A and B. The y-axis is the averaged percentage.

Comment: @ChunLimPan No worries, I've edited my answer to reflect that change - hopefully it's what you're looking for.